# Can't stop listening on local ip SimpleTCP [C#]

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, ip, port

So I have my form1.cs and a different class called TCP-Control.cs. This is the `tcpcontrol` below. The form1 buttons clicks just simple call these methods.

```cs
public SimpleTcpServer voidRayServer = new SimpleTcpServer();

public void ServerOffline()
{
    voidRayServer.Stop();
}

public void ServerOnline()
{
    Form1 warpGate1 = new Form1();

    string ipAdress = warpGate1.IPAdress;
    string port = warpGate1.ServerPort;
    
    IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(ipAdress);

    voidRayServer.Start(ip, Convert.ToInt32(port));
    warpGate1.TextBoxStatus += "hey";
}
```

I call these methods from form1 and starting the server is no problem. But I have now tried everything and I can't get the listening to stop with the `ServerOffline()` method. The crazy thing is if I try doing

```cs
voidRayServer.Start();
```

and immediately after

```cs
voidRayServer.Stop();
```

the server stops and I can see it's not listening in cmd with the `netstat -ano` command.

I am completely out of ideas and this feels like it's so simple yet it's not working. I don't want to do:

```cs
Application.Restart();
```

Because that would close the port but it looks bad for a program in my opinion.

Comment: You wrote that when you call `voidRayServer.Stop()` - `it's not listening ...`. Isn't it expected behaviour?

Comment: I call voidRayServer.stop on a different button from form1 class. I call start first then I check netstat -ano on cmd and the server is listening, then I try to end it with the stop method and nothing happens.

Comment: When you call nestat  - what is the status of the connection? TIME_WAIT?

Comment: It says Listening

Comment: I suggest you to provide a github repository with complete sample. Because this test   https://github.com/BrandonPotter/SimpleTCP/blob/61f1932201a7c5633ad2f003c97c83c31541fc85/SimpleTCP.Tests/ServerTests.cs#L26 works

Comment: Where is the code of the SimpleTcpServer class?

Comment: https://github.com/Vraces/servertest

Comment: repo is broken: no VoidRayServer.csproj . Clone it and try to run